# How can I create pie charts to show the percentage of licenses and storage used in Tableau?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

Tableau Dashboard - Issue creating Pie Charts

Hi,

I am trying to create two pie charts;

1 - To show the percentage of licenses used vs not used. Fields are SUM(licenses_used) and SUM(license_ceiling)

2 - To show the percentage of storage used vs not used. Fields are SUM(storage_used) and SUM(storage_ceiling)

I have used Chatgpt and cannot get the correct set up in Tableau 2019 edition and need to have this complete for a project. Could anyone help me get this sorted?

Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks!